# R plot generates completely blank PNG

Tags: r, fonts, cluster-computing

I'm running an R script on a Beowulf computing cluster, and it generates a blank PNG whenever the script runs on one of the compute nodes. Running on the head node works fine.

To try and diagnose the problem, I stripped down my script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

the_plot <- function()
{
    x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 100)
    y <- pbeta(x, 1, 10)
    plot(
            x,
            y,
            xlab = "False Positive Rate",
            ylab = "Average true positive rate",
            type = "l"
    )

}

png(file='plot_test.png', width=400, height=300, type='cairo')
par(family='sans', cex=1, mar=c(5,5,1,1))
the_plot()
dev.off()
```

When I run that on the head node, it generates a curve, axes, and labels. On a compute node, the labels don't appear, so it may be a font problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a previous problem with the same symptoms, plus an error message like this:

> Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

I found that error described on [stata.com's support page](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/unix/fontconfig-error/), and I got rid of it by mapping `/etc/fonts` to the compute nodes. The error message was gone, but the plots were still blank, so maybe there was another folder that still needed to be mapped.

I installed `strace` and traced which files the script was loading when I ran it successfully on the head node. I also traced when it ran unsuccessfully on the compute node.

```
strace -r -o strace.txt ./plot_test.R
bpsh 0 strace -r -o strace_n0.txt ./plot_test.R
```

After cleaning a lot of noise out of the files and comparing the two, I found that the script was loading `/usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2`, `/usr/share/fonts`, and `/var/cache/fontconfig`. None of those were mapped to the compute nodes.

Mapping folders to the compute nodes is controlled through `/etc/exports` and `/etc/beowulf/fstab`, as described in the [Scyld documentation](http://gilgamesh.cheme.cmu.edu/scyld-doc/administration-guide/nfs.html). After mapping all of those folders, the plots worked.